# How to use nested p tags in CSS and Bootstrap boxes?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is the image that I have:

[image]
I am not sure how to do make the text Lieu, Suchy, Prix, CHF 2'250 to be align like in image. And because I'm new to bootstrap too I want to know if what I did is correct.

```css
.boxes-images img {
  width: 100%;
}
.boxes-images h4 {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #8C1211;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.boxes-images .details {
  background-color: #D6D6D6;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-page">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 boxes-images">
      <img src="images/automobile.jpg">
      <h4>IMMOBILIER</h4>
      <div class="details">
        <p>Magnifique et spacieux 4,5 pieces: 1mios de loyer</p>
        <p>Lieu<span>suchy</span>
          <p>
            <p>Prix<span>CHF 2'250</span>
            </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 boxes-images">
      <img src="images/automobile.jpg">
      <h4>IMMOBILIER</h4>
      <div class="details">
        <p>Magnifique et spacieux 4,5 pieces: 1mios de loyer</p>
        <p>Lieu<span>suchy</span>
          <p>
            <p>Prix<span>CHF 2'250</span>
            </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 boxes-images">
      <img src="images/automobile.jpg">
      <h4>IMMOBILIER</h4>
      <div class="details">
        <p>Magnifique et spacieux 4,5 pieces: 1mios de loyer</p>
        <p>Lieu<span>suchy</span>
          <p>
            <p>Prix<span>CHF 2'250</span>
            </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 boxes-images">
      <img src="images/automobile.jpg">
      <h4>IMMOBILIER</h4>
      <div class="details">
        <p>Magnifique et spacieux 4,5 pieces: 1mios de loyer</p>
        <p>Lieu<span>suchy</span>
          <p>
            <p>Prix<span>CHF 2'250</span>
            </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 boxes-images">
      <img src="images/automobile.jpg">
      <h4>IMMOBILIER</h4>
      <div class="details">
        <p>Magnifique et spacieux 4,5 pieces: 1mios de loyer</p>
        <p>Lieu<span>suchy</span>
          <p>
            <p>Prix<span>CHF 2'250</span>
            </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 boxes-images">
      <img src="images/automobile.jpg">
      <h4>IMMOBILIER</h4>
      <div class="details">
        <p>Magnifique et spacieux 4,5 pieces: 1mios de loyer</p>
        <p>Lieu<span>suchy</span>
          <p>
            <p>Prix<span>CHF 2'250</span>
            </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 boxes-images">
      <img src="images/automobile.jpg">
      <h4>IMMOBILIER</h4>
      <div class="details">
        <p>Magnifique et spacieux 4,5 pieces: 1mios de loyer</p>
        <p>Lieu<span>suchy</span>
          <p>
            <p>Prix<span>CHF 2'250</span>
            </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 boxes-images">
      <img src="images/automobile.jpg">
      <h4>IMMOBILIER</h4>
      <div class="details">
        <p>Magnifique et spacieux 4,5 pieces: 1mios de loyer</p>
        <p>Lieu<span>suchy</span>
          <p>
            <p>Prix<span>CHF 2'250</span>
            </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You cannot have nested `p` tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your markup, the simplest way is to float the `span` element inside those parent `p` elements:

```
.boxes-images .details p span{
  float: right;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yq3fx8dj/)

Or use bootstraps [`.pull-right`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L6519) class:

```
.pull-right {
  float: right !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `float:right` to your `span tag` which is placed inside `p tag`. You can even achieve spacing between `p`  and `span` using `pseudo element` too or by assigning `class` to your `span tag`.

```
.boxes-images .details > p > span{
  float:right;
}

/*Using Pseudo element*/

.boxes-images .details > p > span:before{
 content:'';
 margin-left:50%;
 background:#111;
}

/* Add pull-right to span tag works and you don't need to add any custom css,
as pull-right is pre-defined class of bootstrap that floats your element to right,
so add that to all your span tag too work*/

<div class="details">
<p>Magnifique et spacieux 4,5 pieces: 1mios de loyer</p>
<p>Lieu<span class="pull-right">suchy</span>
<p>
   <p>Prix<span class="pull-right">CHF 2'250</span>
</p>
</div>
```